# How to narrow UITableView cell height if there is dynamic structure in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have a tableView and cells. The Cells are loaded from a xib and they have a label with automatic height. I need to narrow one cell if the user taps on it.

I have tried hiding - doesn't work
I have tried `removeFromSuperView()`-  doesn't work

Is there any alternative?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When setting up your tableViewCell store the height anchor you want to update

```
var yourLabelHeightAnchor: NSLayoutConstraint?
private func setupLayout() {
     yourLabelHeightAnchor = yourLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50)
     // Deactivate your height anchor as you want first the content to determine the height
     yourLabelHeightAnchor?.isActive = false
}
```

When the user clicks on a cell, notify the tableView that the cell is going to change, and activate the height anchor of your cell.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
     let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "YourTableViewCellIdentifier") as? YourCell
     self.tableView.beginUpdates()
     cell?.yourLabelHeightAnchor?.isActive = true
     self.tableView.endUpdates()
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Did you try to do something like this:

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    var result: CGFloat
    if (indexPath.row==0) {
        result = 50 }
    else {result = 130}
    return result
}
```

This is just an example where height is changed for the first row. I tested on my application and it gave result like this.
[image]

Comment: I need just if block. Just i will change cell size to 75 thats it . But if i add this xcode ask me "where is else block" . maybe i can return self.cell.height like

Comment: I don't think I understand your concern. Did you copy my example? You can find usefull this documentation regarding if statement: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Statements.html